# error in accessing global array from other method of same class in java

Tags: java, arrays, global-variables

I am trying to implement Queue ADT in Java. I just have a single class with four methods: main, enqueue, dequeue, view(yet to implement this feature). So when I try to compile the code, I get the following error:

`C:\Users\Sandeep Sharma\Documents\Software Project files\JAVA Programs\queue Implementation>javac mainClass.java
mainClass.java:53: error: cannot find symbol
                        array(++front) = input;
                        ^
  symbol:   method array(int)
  location: class mainClass
mainClass.java:64: error: cannot find symbol
                        System.out.println("The value is: " + array(rear));
                                                              ^
  symbol:   method array(int)
  location: class mainClass
2 errors`

I tried declaring the int array as static as `static int[] array = new int[10]`, but that is not working.

The requirement is: To access The array in all the methods to perform Queue related operations on them.

My code is:

```
// Implementing Queue data structure
import java.util.*;
class mainClass{

    // global variables 
    static int front=0,rear=0;
    int[] array = new int[10];

    //main method
    public static void main(String args[]){
        // variable declaration
        int runChoice=0,opChoice=0;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        // user control menu

        do{
            System.out.println("***Select option***:");
            System.out.println("1 to enqueue an element.");
            System.out.println("2 to dequeue element.");
            System.out.println("3 to view element.");
            System.out.print("Your Option: ");
            opChoice = scan.nextInt();
            switch(opChoice){
                case 1: enqueue();
                break;

                case 2: dequeue();
                break;

                case 3: view();
                break;

                default: System.out.println("Invalid input!");
            }

            System.out.print("Enter 1 to continue operation: ");
            runChoice = scan.nextInt();
        }while(runChoice==1);
    }

    public static void enqueue(){
        int input;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        if(front == 9)
            System.out.println("Queue is full.");

        else{
            System.out.print("Enter your input: ");
            input = scan.nextInt();
            array(++front) = input;
        }
    }

    public static void dequeue(){
        if(front == rear){
            System.out.println("Queue is empty");
            front = rear = 0;
        }

        else{
            System.out.println("The value is: " + array(rear));
            rear++;
        }
    }

    public static void view(){

    }


}
```

Comment: use arrays like this: `array[front]` , i.e with square brackets.

Comment: Thank you, Oswald. I did as you suggested i.e. changed the declaration from `int[] array = new int[10]` but the error is still same.

Comment: your declaration is fine, the way you index it needs to change

Answer (score 0):

Your `array` is not a class variable (not static) and can only be accessed by an instance of your `mainClass`. For now declare `array` to be static. Afterwards I would recommend to read the Java Documentation - [Understanding Class Members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

---

**Edit**
As @Oswald mentioned you also have to use square brackets. `array` is not a method.

You might want to use an IDE for now.

Comment: Thank you ZyexalI, I made the change as you suggested `static int[] array = new int[10];`, but the error is still the same.

Comment: As for now your code has several problems. For the start with Java you might want to use a Java IDE. After changing the backet thingy and the variable declaration the code will compile but fail for example for unexpected inputs.

Comment: All right @Zyexal, Thank you for your time and help!